# How to create a zero vector?

Tags: math-mode, arrows, vector

`$\vec{0}$` and `$\overrightarrow{0}$`  generate the following:

[image: pdf output]

[image: pdf output]

The first arrow is decentered (it assumes an italic font), the second one is clearly too large. How to get an upright version of `\vec`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `esvect` package provides nice vector arrows in most cases:
The command is `\vv` (not `\vec`) and it provides a centered, non-slanted (better 'upright') arrow, which is shorter than the arrow given by `\overrightarrow`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{esvect}


\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
esvect:   & $\vv{0}$ \\
amsmath:  & $\overrightarrow{0}$ \\
standard: & $\vec{0}$ 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

From Bernard's comment: `esvect` defines 8 different arrow (head) types, which can be chosen by `\usepackage[a]{esvect}` to `\usepackage[h]{esvect}`. Omitting the optional argument will use the (default) `d` variant

Comment: And here I was expecting one of your amazing macros! Nah, just kidding. Easiest answer = best answer.

Comment: @1010011010: My amazing macros? ;-) Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: You might add esvect defines $8$ different arrow tips.

Comment: @Bernard: Good suggestion! I'll do immediately.

Comment: i think `\overrightarrow` isn't the right answer in any event.  what is really needed is an arrow with an "upright" (e.g. "not italic") arrowhead.  something to think about.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: `\overrightarrow` was just used as a 'bad' example. I wouldn't apply it for myself.

Answer (score 3):

May be for this particular case have `\0` defined

```
\newcommand\0{\kern-1.2pt\vec{\kern1.2pt 0}}
```

In that case whatever definition you choose, you can change it at the end if there's a more practical way.

Comment: `\0` looks strange, but seems to work (+1)

Comment: Apart from proposing this particular definition to remove the displacement of the arrow, what I meant is that if one defines `\0` and then uses it along the document, at the end he can choose wether he prefers `\vv{0}` or any other definition.